# How to restart services on remote server in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do something very simple but have lost my way. I have this script that works almost perfect. It goes into a list of servers checks for 2 services and checks if they are running. Then, it generates a list of servers that are running or stopped. Now, what I need it to do is to restart the service when it finds that it is stopped...

```
$Computers = Get-Content -path C:\computers.txt
$Computerobject = $null
FOREACH ( $Computer IN $Computers )
{
    TRY
    {
        $Services = $null
        $Services = (Get-Service -Name 'CrystalToPDF','Bradware - BoxUploadService' -computername $Computer -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Status, Name, DisplayName )
        Add-Member -InputObject $Services -NotePropertyName ComputerName -NotePropertyValue $Computer
        $ComputerProperties = [ordered] @{ComputerName=$Services.ComputerName; ServiceName=$Services.Name; Status=$Services.Status}
        $Computerobject = New-Object PSObject -Property $ComputerProperties
        $Computerobject
    }
        CATCH
        {
            Write-Host "Both services are not installed on $Computer." -ForegroundColor Red
        }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to start the service, pipe it to `Start-Service`. Or just simply start it using the same cmdlet

Comment: add this after your 2nd `$Services` variable: `if($Services.Status -eq "Stopped"){ Get-Service -Name 'CrystalToPDF','Bradware - BoxUploadService' -computername $Computer -ErrorAction Stop | Start-Service}`

Comment: $Services = $null
        $Services = if($Services.Status -eq "Stopped"){ Get-Service -Name 'CrystalToPDF','Bradware - BoxUploadService' -computername $Computer -ErrorAction Stop | Start-Service| Select-Object Status, Name, DisplayName }
        Add-Member -InputObject $Services -NotePropertyName ComputerName -NotePropertyValue $Computer
        $ComputerProperties = [ordered] @{ComputerName=$Services.ComputerName; ServiceName=$Services.Name; Status=$Services.Status}
        $Computerobject = New-Object PSObject -Property $ComputerProperties
        $Computerobject

Comment: I added it and ran it but got a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Following from my comment.

Like this:

```
$Computers = Get-Content -path C:\computers.txt
$Computerobject = $null
FOREACH ( $Computer IN $Computers )
{
    TRY
    {
        $Services = $null
        $Services = (Get-Service -Name 'CrystalToPDF','Bradware - BoxUploadService' -computername $Computer -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Status, Name, DisplayName )
            if($Services.Status -eq "Stopped"){ Get-Service -Name 'CrystalToPDF','Bradware - BoxUploadService' -computername $Computer | Start-Service}
        Add-Member -InputObject $Services -NotePropertyName ComputerName -NotePropertyValue $Computer
        $ComputerProperties = [ordered] @{ComputerName=$Services.ComputerName; ServiceName=$Services.Name; Status=$Services.Status}
        $Computerobject = New-Object PSObject -Property $ComputerProperties
        $Computerobject
    }
        CATCH
        {
            Write-Host "Both services are not installed on $Computer." -ForegroundColor Red
        }
}
```